# BigQuery, fill missing values with Linear interpolation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in Bigquery with data every 30 minutes, I want to show the data every 5 minutes, currently I am using this query to fill the null values with the existing values

```
SELECT
SETTLEMENTDATE,DUID,
LAST_VALUE(SCADAVALUE ignore nulls) OVER (
    PARTITION BY DUID ORDER BY SETTLEMENTDATE) AS SCADAVALUE from x
```

instead, is it possible to do Linear interpolation, something like this

[image]

I have the column settlement date which is by 5 minutes, the column SCADAVALUEORIGIN Which has a value very 30 minutes, otherwise it is null, I want to add a column SCADAINTERPOLATION, which spread the values evenly between two the values of 30 minute, another issue is, as I refresh the data every 5 minutes, the last value will show null for (5,10,15,20,25) minutes, I hope, my explanation is clear

Comment: sorry, I updated the title

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question would help.  It would also help if you shows what values were missing and explained how you want to calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(SETTLEMENTDATE, INTERVAL 5 * i MINUTE) AS SETTLEMENTDATE, 
  IF(i = 0, SCADAVALUEORIGIN, NULL) AS SCADAVALUEORIGIN,
  SCADAVALUEORIGIN AS SCADAVALUE,
  ROUND(SCADAVALUEORIGIN + IFNULL((next_value - SCADAVALUEORIGIN) / 6 * i, 0), 3) AS SCADAINTERPOLATION
FROM (
  SELECT SETTLEMENTDATE, SCADAVALUEORIGIN, 
    LEAD(SCADAVALUEORIGIN) OVER(ORDER BY SETTLEMENTDATE) next_value,
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5)) i
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can speculate that you want something like this:

```
select timestamp_add(t.ts, interval min minute),
       (val * (30 - min) +
        lead(val) over (order by ts) * min
       ) / 30
from t cross join
     unnest(generate_array(0, 25, 5)) min;
```

Comment: sorry, I added a better explanation, I hope

Comment: @Mim . . . This should do what you want, if you just filter down to the rows that have values.

Comment: how about the rows without values ?

Comment: @Mim . . . This adds in the rows every five minutes between the rows with values.