# How to fill irregularly missing values with linear interepolation in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have data which has missing values irregulaly, and I'd like to convert it with a certain interval with liner interpolation using BigQuery Standard SQL.

Specifically, I have data like this:

```
# data is missing irregulary
+------+-------+
| time | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 | 3.0   |
|    5 | 5.0   |
|    7 | 1.0   |
|    9 | 8.0   |
|   10 | 4.0   |
+------+-------+
```

and I'd like to convert this table as follows:

```
# interpolated with interval of 1
+------+--------------------+
| time | value_interpolated |
+------+--------------------+
|    1 | 3.0                |
|    2 | 3.5                |
|    3 | 4.0                |
|    4 | 4.5                |
|    5 | 5.0                |
|    6 | 3.0                |
|    7 | 1.0                |
|    8 | 4.5                |
|    9 | 8.0                |
|   10 | 4.0                |
+------+--------------------+
```

Any smart soluton for this?

Supplement: this question is similar to [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199557/bigquery-fill-missing-values-with-linear-interpolation) but different in that the data is missing irregulaly.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the logic of putting 3.0 in time=6.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is calculated as the average value of time=5(value is 5.0) and time=7(value is 1.0)

Comment: Could you explain how you have arrived at values 3.5,4,4.5 for the time(2,3,4)

Comment: Thank you. It's interepolating data between time=1(value is 3) and time=5(value is 5.0) linerarly. So, intereval of 0.5 in  the firsrt 3.5, 4.0, 4.5  is calculated as (value 5.0 - vallue 3.0) /(time 5 -time 1) = 2/4 = 0.5.

Comment: Thanks, going by that logic should the value of time=8 be (value 8.0- value 1.0)/(time 9 - Time 7) = 7/2 = 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select time,
  ifnull(value, start_value + (end_value - start_value) / (end_tick - start_tick) * (time - start_tick)) as value_interpolated
from (
  select time, value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls) over win1 as start_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win1 as start_value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls) over win2 as end_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win2 as end_value,
  from (
    select time, t.time as tick, value
    from (
      select generate_array(min(time), max(time)) times
      from `project.dataset.table`
    ), unnest(times) time 
    left join `project.dataset.table` t
    using(time)
  )
  window win1 as (order by time desc rows between current row and unbounded following),
  win2 as (order by time rows between current row and unbounded following)
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I solved with this answer. I posted another question related to this issue(much more difficult), I'd like you to check it if you don't mind. The link for new question is as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829772/how-to-fill-irregularly-missing-time-series-values-with-linear-interepolation-by

Comment: sure. answered too :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to solve this in Postgresql.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c560dd9a8db095920d0a15834b6768f1

```
with data
   as (select time
              ,lead(time) over(order by time) as next_time
              ,value
              ,lead(value) over(order by time) as next_value
              ,(lead(value) over(order by time)- value) as val_diff
              ,(lead(time) over(order by time)- time) as time_diff
          from t
      )
select *
       ,generate_series- time as grp
       ,case when generate_series- time = 0 then
                  value
             else value + (val_diff*1.0/time_diff)*(generate_series-time)*1.0
         end as val_grp
  from data
cross join generate_series(time, coalesce(next_time-1,time))


+------+-----------------+-----+-------------------------+
| time | generate_series | grp |         val_grp         |
+------+-----------------+-----+-------------------------+
|    1 |               1 |   0 |                     3.0 |
|    1 |               2 |   1 | 3.500000000000000000000 |
|    1 |               3 |   2 | 4.000000000000000000000 |
|    1 |               4 |   3 | 4.500000000000000000000 |
|    5 |               5 |   0 |                     5.0 |
|    5 |               6 |   1 |     3.00000000000000000 |
|    7 |               7 |   0 |                     1.0 |
|    7 |               8 |   1 |     4.50000000000000000 |
|    9 |               9 |   0 |                     8.0 |
|   10 |              10 |   0 |                     4.0 |
+------+-----------------+-----+-------------------------+
```

I believe the syntax would be different in BigQuery using UNNEST and GENERATE_ARRAY as follows. You could give it a try.

```
 with data
       as (select time
                  ,lead(time) over(order by time) as next_time
                  ,value
                  ,lead(value) over(order by time) as next_value
                  ,(lead(value) over(order by time)- value) as val_diff
                  ,(lead(time) over(order by time)- time) as time_diff
              from t
          )
    select *
           ,generate_series- time as grp
           ,case when generate_series- time = 0 then
                      value
                 else value + (val_diff*1.0/time_diff)*(generate_series-time)*1.0
             end as val_grp
      from data
    cross join  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(time, coalesce(next_time-1,time))) as generate_series
```

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery you can generate the extra rows for each row using `generate_array()`.  Then you can use `lead()` to get information from the next row and some arithmetic for interpolation:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as time, 3.0 as value union all
      select 5 , 5.0 union all  
      select 7 , 1.0 union all
      select 9 , 8.0 union all
      select 10 , 4.0 
     ),
     tt as (
      select t.*,
             lead(time) over (order by time) as next_time,
             lead(value) over (order by time) as next_value
      from t
     )
select coalesce(n, tt.time) as time, 
       (case when n = tt.time or n is null then value
             else tt.value + (tt.next_value - tt.value) * (n - tt.time) / (tt.next_time - tt.time)
        end) as value
from tt left join
     unnest(generate_array(tt.time, tt.next_time - 1, 1)) n
     on true
order by 1;
```

Note:  You have a column called `time` that contains an integer.  If this is really a date/time data type of some type, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with more appropriate sample data and desired results -- if you don't see how to adapt this answer.