# How to fill irregularly missing time-series values with linear interepolation by each user in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, interpolation, missing-data

I have data which has missing ***time series*** values irregulaly ***for each users***, and I'd like to convert it with a certain interval with liner interpolation using BigQuery Standard SQL.

```
+------+---------------------+-------+
| name |        time         | value |
+------+---------------------+-------+
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:01:00 |     3 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:05:00 |     5 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:07:00 |     1 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:09:00 |     8 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:10:00 |     4 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:01:00 |     7 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:04:00 |     1 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:05:00 |    10 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:09:00 |     6 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:10:00 |     7 |
+------+---------------------+-------+
```

and I'd like to convert it as follows:

```
+------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+
| name |        time         | value |                 |
+------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:01:00 | 3     |                 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:02:00 | 3.5   | <= interpolaetd |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:03:00 | 4     | <= interpolaetd |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:04:00 | 4.5   | <= interpolaetd |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:05:00 | 5     |                 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:06:00 | 3     | <= interpolaetd |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:07:00 | 1     |                 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:08:00 | 4.5   | <= interpolaetd |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:09:00 | 8     |                 |
| Jane | 2020-11-14 09:10:00 | 4     |                 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:01:00 | 7     |                 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:02:00 | 5     | <= interpolaetd |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:03:00 | 3     | <= interpolaetd |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:04:00 | 1     |                 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:05:00 | 10    |                 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:06:00 | 9     | <= interpolaetd |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:07:00 | 8     | <= interpolaetd |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:08:00 | 7     | <= interpolaetd |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:09:00 | 6     |                 |
| Kay  | 2020-11-14 09:10:00 | 7     |                 |
+------+---------------------+-------+-----------------+
```

Can I ask you some smart solution for this?

Suppliment: This is an aplication problem for [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816885/how-to-fill-irregularly-missing-values-with-linear-interepolation-in-bigquery). It's very similar but different in that this data is ***time seris*** data and it has names for ***each users***.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery SQL

```
#standardSQL
select name, time,
    ifnull(value, start_value 
      + (end_value - start_value) / timestamp_diff(end_tick, start_tick, minute) * timestamp_diff(time, start_tick, minute)
    ) as value_interpolated
from (
    select name, time, value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls ) over win1 as start_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win1 as start_value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls ) over win2 as end_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win2 as end_value,
    from (
        select name, time, t.time as tick, value
        from (
            select name, generate_timestamp_array(min(time), max(time), interval 1 minute) times
            from `project.dataset.table`
            group by name
        )
        cross join unnest(times) time 
        left join `project.dataset.table` t 
        using(name, time)
    )
    window 
        win1 as (partition by name order by time desc rows between current row and unbounded following),
        win2 as (partition by name order by time rows between current row and unbounded following)
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is very nice. Is there a point where SQL UDF's would be faster to implement as a Javascript UDF? I am looking at a problem similar to above, except that the missing data is not uniformly spaced but is coming from a second list of times. I think I can map your SQL answer over, but Javascript would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very different from your previous question. Starting from the accepted answer, you could do:

```
select name, time,
    ifnull(value, start_value + (end_value - start_value) / (end_tick - start_tick) * (time - start_tick)) as value_interpolated
from (
    select name, time, value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls ) over win1 as start_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win1 as start_value,
    first_value(tick ignore nulls ) over win2 as end_tick,
    first_value(value ignore nulls) over win2 as end_value,
    from (
        select name, time, t.time as tick, value
        from (
            select name, generate_array(min(time), max(time)) times
            from `project.dataset.table`
            group by name
        )
        cross join unnest(times) time 
        left join `project.dataset.table` t using(name, time)
    )
    window 
        win1 as (partition by name order by time desc rows between current row and unbounded following),
        win2 as (partition by name order by time rows between current row and unbounded following)
)
```