# Change FROM Table Name Dynamically based on date in Bigquery Scheduled Query

Tags: sql, database, firebase, google-bigquery, analytics

[image]

Please refer the screenshot attached.. i need to set up a bigquery scheduled task to pull info into a permanent table. the from table name will dynamically change each day so i can pull that day info only and append it to the existing table. any help will be highly appreciated[image]

please see the second image...i tried to achieve using this.. but i am unable to convert yester into String.. and add it ..

actually this was the query i am looking to implement this..

SELECT event_date, event_timestamp, event_name,
(select value.double_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'percentage') as percentage,
(select value.double_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'seconds') as seconds
FROM xscore-prod.analytics_229726387.events_*
WHERE event_name = "spent_time_in_activity"

how can i implement the script into this

Comment: Your query suggests that you are using sharding.  I would recommend that you switch to partitioned tables.  Even google recommends this:   "The recommended best practice is to use date/timestamp/datetime partitioned tables instead of date-sharded tables."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) to generate and execute queries  dynamically in BigQuery:

```
DECLARE yesterday STRING DEFAULT FORMAT_DATE("%F", (DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)));
DECLARE query STRING;
SET query = "SELECT * FROM `xscore-prod.analytics_229726387.events_" || yesterday || "` LIMIT 1000";
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  actually this was the query i am looking to implement this.. SELECT 
  event_date,
  event_timestamp,
  event_name,  
  (select value.double_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'percentage') as percentage,
  (select value.double_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'seconds') as seconds,
   (SELECT PARSE_DATE ("%Y%m%d", event_date))As Date
  
FROM
  `xscore-prod.analytics_229726387.events_*`
  WHERE event_name = "spent_time_in_activity"   how can i implement the above script into this..

Comment: Hmm... Could you add an example of input data you have and an example of output data you need (in text format) to your question like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829772/how-to-fill-irregularly-missing-time-series-values-with-linear-interepolation-by)?

Comment: actually i was able to get the desired output data using the above sql.. but when i set up scheduled query the datasource for FROM table changes everyday.. so i want my sql also changes that dynamic source.. using some functions.. so i just can run the scheduled query on specific table and append the data to the existing permanent table.

Comment: The `yesterday` variable will be changing everyday, thus the `query` will also be changing it's `FROM` table everyday. If you add this script to the scheduled query it will select data from different table everyday.

Comment: but i dont know how to add this script to the existing query..can you help

Comment: Go to the BigQuery UI. Go to the list of Scheduled queries (choose `Scheduled queries` in the menu to the left). Click your scheduled query. Click `EDIT` in the top right corner. Edit as required and press `Save query`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

select *
from `<project>.<dataset>.events_*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20220525'

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Answer (score 2):

If your table comes from Firebase Analytics, try this:

```
WHERE
  event_name = 'your_event_name'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```

Here I'm querying yesterday only as your example.

Comment: My query is `SELECT * FROM stocks_idx.* where _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'ABBA'` I got this error `BigQuery error: Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "." at [1:25]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an underscore after the table name.
The format of the google analytics table is `analytics_(propertyid).events_(datestring)`

```
select event_date,sum(case when event_name="session_start" then 1 else 0 end  ) as session,sum(case when event_name="add_to_cart" then 1 else 0 end  ) as atc,traffic_source.name,traffic_source.medium,traffic_source.source from `your_project_name.analytics_(propertyid).events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY))
group by 1,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover,

```
    _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 day)) ),
```

is totally legit